# Training a SOM in batch mode

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, self-organizing-maps, parallel-computing

I was reading the [Somoclu parallel implementation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1422.pdf) of Self-Organizing Maps (SOMs) and they say that in order to make the algorithm parallelizable, a batch training mode has to be followed. The equation to update the weights is given in the 4th page of the document I linked above:

$$\mathbf{w}_k(t_f)=
\frac{\sum_{t=t_i}^{t_f} h_{bk}(t) \mathbf{x}(t)}
{\sum_{t=t_i}^{t_f} h_{bk}(t)}$$

Where $h_{bk}$ is the vecinity function. I don't understand why that formulation works. Shouldn't the factor $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{w})$ be used at some point to achieve convergence? What troubles me is that past values of the weights are not used in the update rule.

Does that equation make sense? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;dr:** yes it makes sense.

---

**Explanation:**

There are two main algorithms for the training of SOMs: the online and the batch algorithm. In the **online algorithm**, the weights are updated with

$w_i(t+1) = w(i) + \alpha(t)\cdot h(t)\cdot(x(t) - w_i(t))$

with the learning rate $\alpha$, the neighborhood distance weight $h$, the datapoint $x$ at the current iteration $t$. With this, you iteratively adapt the SOM to the dataset.

The **batch algorithm** does this in full dataset batches. The influence of one datapoint $x(t)$ on a specific weight $w_i(t)$ is controlled by the neighborhood distance weight $h$ which depends on the (grid) distance between the best matching unit (BMU) of the datapoint $x(t)$ and the weight $w_i(t)$. The previous state of the SOM is not included in the form of a $(x(t) - w_i(t))$ term but is intrinsically included in the BMU calculation for each datapoint.